# get result for 2 different tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql. I have a requirement, please see the tables below

```
grand_score_master

autoid | user_id   | package_id | grand_level | timestamp | timestring
55     | CBS_00002 | s78c_e4vt6 | 1           | ...       | ...
58     | CBS_00002 | d47kndffqc | 3           | ...       | ...
64     | CBS_00002 | d47kndffqc | 1           | ...       | ...
65     | CBS_00002 | d47kndffqc | 2           | ...       | ...


mega_score_master

autoid | user_id   | package_id | mega_level | timestamp | timestring
1      | CBS_00002 | d47kndffqc | 1          | ...       | ...


expected result

user_id   | package_id | max_grand_leve | max_mega_level
CBS_00002 | s78c_e4vt6 | 1              | 0
CBS_00002 | d47kndffqc | 3              | 1
```

`package_id` and `user_id` is are in both tables.

I am trying to make a query where I will pass a user_id say 'CBS_00002' and query will return `max(grand_level)` and `max(mega_level)` by matching/grouping common package_id from both the table for that user.

I tried this

```
SELECT  max(grand_score_master.grand_level),
        grand_score_master.package_id,
        max(mega_score_master.mega_level)
FROM    grand_score_master
INNER JOIN mega_score_master
ON      mega_score_master.package_id = grand_score_master.package_id
WHERE   user_id='CBS_00002'
GROUP BY grand_score_master.package_id
```

But it only return result for **d47kndffqc** because **s78c_e4vt6** is not present in `mega_score_master`

Need some help.

Comment: Linking images is bad practice, because if links break this question will be of no use for future readers. Post sample data and expected output as well formatted text instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, you only need to change your `inner join` to a `left join`; this will preserve all the rows from the first table, regardless of being matched in the second one or not:

```
SELECT  max(t1.grand_level) max_grand_level,
        t1.package_id,
        IFNULL(max(t2.mega_level), 0) max_mega_level
FROM    grand_score_master t1
LEFT JOIN
        mega_score_master t2
ON      t2.package_id = t1.package_id
WHERE   t1.user_id='CBS_00002'
GROUP BY t1.package_id
```

I also added aliases to your tables, so that the query results a bit more compact.

Comment: dear it works, but is there any way to convert NULL to 0 in this query

Comment: Ok I got it IFNULL(column,0)